# Analyzing Code with Steps

Tags: c++

So I know the output of the code is 8 2 but could someone show me how the value of 
  i and j change after each step please.

Here is the link for the code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i; int j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    { 
        if(i % 2 == 1) 
        { 
            i = i + 2; j++;
        }
        else
        { 
            j = j + 2; 
        }
        j--;
    }

    cout << i <<" "<< j;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen a debugger in your live? Now is a good point to look out for that magic tool :-)

Comment: If you just insert a copy of `cout << i <<" "<< j;` right after the beginning `{` of the loop, you'll get a printout of the values of `i` and `j` at the start of each iteration. Except for the first time, these are also the values after the previous iteration. The values at the end of the last iteration would still get printed after the loop as you do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be

```
   int i; int j = 0;           // i==? j==0
----------------------------------------------
   for ( i = 0;                // i==0 j==0
                i < 7;         // TRUE
   if(i % 2 == 1)              // FALSE
   j = j + 2;                  // i==0 j==2
   j--;                        // i==0 j==1
                       i++)    // i==1 j==1
----------------------------------------------
                i < 7;         // TRUE
   if(i % 2 == 1)              // TRUE
   i = i + 2; j++;             // i==3 j==2
   j--;                        // i==3 j==1
                       i++)    // i==4 j==1
----------------------------------------------
                i < 7;         // TRUE
   if(i % 2 == 1)              // FALSE
   j = j + 2;                  // i==4 j==3
   j--;                        // i==4 j==2
                       i++)    // i==5 j==2
----------------------------------------------
                i < 7;         // TRUE
   if(i % 2 == 1)              // TRUE
   i = i + 2; j++;             // i==7 j==3
   j--;                        // i==7 j==2
                       i++)    // i==8 j==2
----------------------------------------------
                i < 7;         // FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, i understood it really quickly and you showed every step, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Simplified your code by removing `j++` from `if-true`, changing `j=j+2` to `j++` in `if-false` so that `j--` after the `if_else` shall be removed. And also understanding code becomes easier.

```
int main()
{
    int i; int j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    { 
        if(i % 2 == 1) 
        { 
            i = i + 2;//add 2 in i for odd i
        }
        else
        { 
            j++; //add 1 in j for even i
        }

    }

    cout << i <<" "<< j;
}
```

Explanation :

```
i=0,j=0
```

---

```
Since, i=0 (even)
j=1 (even so j++)
i=1 (i++ for-loop)
```

---

```
i=3 (odd so add 2)
i=4 (i++ for-loop)
j=1 (unchanged)
```

---

```
i=4 (even)
j=2 (even so j++)
i=5 (i++ for-loop)
```

---

```
i=7 (odd so add 2)
j=2 (unchanged)
i=8 (i++ for-loop)
```

---

```
i=8 (i<7 for-loop exit)
```

**`i=2` & `j=8`**

Comment: Maybe someone felt this wasn't an answer to the question. Since you modified the original code, this is obviously not a step-be-step explanation of the original code. You get the same result but that's kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @4386427 the down-vote was for my earlier answer, where i had traced it for original code. But since that code looked inefficient(with unnecessary increments & decrements), I just modified it.

Comment: Good to know it helped.